# Transitions with overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have two divs which are overlapping, set by my CSS as shown below.

HTML:

```
    <body onLoad="present();">
    <div class="pre-wrap">
        <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Pre Logo" style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;" />
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.pre-wrap {
height: 700px;
width: 900px;
opacity: 1.0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: red;
visibility: visible;
}

.wrap { 
height: 700px;
width: 900px;
opacity: 1.0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: black;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I would like, when the body has loaded, a function to load which does the following: Fades in the image found in the div .pre-wrap, after displaying it for a few seconds, it will fade the image out and the div .pre-wrap will have it's visibility set to hidden. The second div .wrap will then fade in all of its contents.

I tried some simple JS but didn't achieve what I was after.

This question I would say is unique because it has overlapping divs which need visibilities being changed. Please note the overlapping already works, it's just the javascript fading that needs doing.

I tried the following JS which is very simple and works on other projects I've done however it doesn't on this one.

```
function present() {
        $("#logo").fadeIn(3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code. I removed the property visibility in the css. And set the display of #logo to none. The attribute onload in the body is no longer needed.

```js
var fadeTime = 3000;    // Time for fading
var waitingTime = 5000; // Time how long image is visible



$(window).ready(function(){
 $("#logo").fadeIn(fadeTime);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   $(".pre-wrap").fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $(".wrap").delay(fadeTime).fadeIn(fadeTime);
  },fadeTime+waitingTime);
  
});
```

```css
.pre-wrap, .wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 700px;
  width: 900px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  margin: auto;
}

.pre-wrap {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrap { 
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pre-wrap">
  <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Pre Logo" style="display: none; margin: 0 auto;" />
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```